# Encoding with nsstring

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

i am developing an iOS application with uses `UIWebView` and `Javascript`. i have a `javascript` function like this :

```
function(){
.... 
escape(text);
.....
return text;
}
```

and in my UIWebView :

```
NSString *myString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavascript@"function()"];
```

this function return to me a string encoded with the javascript function espace, how i can decode this string with objective C ? thanks for your answers

Comment: It's escape, not espace, I think. "Espace" means "space" (like in Spaceship) in french.

Comment: sorry , it's escape : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encode a NSString with percent escapes use **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding** e.g..

```
NSString * escapedString = [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To decode an already escaped NSString use **stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding** e.g..

```
NSString * unescapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

See Documentation for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)